# Ten Chin or Tein Chien or something else?

Tags: aikido, footwork

Ten chin or Ttein Chien I'm not sure of transliterated spelling, is the footwork
where one foot replaces another/one moves back and the opposite forward,
It should one of the four fundamental primary footwork moves in aikido - irimi, tenkan, irimi tenkan, and "ten chine"

Can someone provide the correct transliteration spelling and possibly link to online resource?

Comment: It would help to cite which lineage of aikido you practice.  Tomiki, Aikikai, and Yoshinkan all have slightly different names for the same underlying concepts.

Comment: You're affiliated with Aikikai.  http://www.aikidofc.com/About_Us.html affiliates with USAF, led by https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yoshimitsu_Yamada, who is Aikikai.

Comment: I believe it is legitimate to call Aikikai mainstream, although my teacher (who learned in the Tomiki lineage) might quibble with that.  The reason it is important is that since (to my memory) Aikikai relies less on  tai sabaki (The Walk), I don't want to reference that as a source; it probably isn't part of your training experience.

Comment: And "Budo" is (loosely) just a term for martial arts. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bud%C5%8D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tenshin is the same as Tenkai
"Tenshin..Pivoting with feet in one position..face other direction.( also called Tenkai )." [Aikido Glossary](http://aikidoshinryukan.weebly.com/uploads/4/6/6/4/.../glossary.doc)

Tsugi Ashi is the "shuffling" step (the first step in tai sabaki - there is an example at about 0:12 on [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HayEdc69vQg), and some more video [here (video good - I don't speak the language in which it is narraged)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gZJvqTwWhHI).  There is a  quick textual description [at "g" in this resource](http://discovering-aikido.com/posture.htm).  Patrick Parker (always an excellent resource for aikido) has [a very nice article on why it is important](http://www.mokurendojo.com/2012/04/tsugiashi-kuzushi-ayumiashi.html).  *edit* [Aikido Journal's definition is somewhat weak](http://members.aikidojournal.com/encyclopedia/tsugiashi/)

Tsugi Ashi is important because it keeps your center of gravity lower and less susceptible to unbalancing.  The alternative (Ayumiashi) requires that you lift your weight and lean backwards slightly as your feet cross. That's a moment of susceptibility.  If you want to see it, get a good judo player to show you how to harvest the foot as it comes forward ([de ashi bari](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IePA98nRc3c) as Patricia reminded me).

Comment: de ashi bari (or hari)  is probably the foot sweep you are referring to :)  or perhaps ko soto gari. depending which direction you take the foot into.

Answer (score 1):

Tenshin is doing an ayumi ashi step forwards followed by a small tenkan, moving offline and adjusting to face uke.

It is the beginning footwork that is done in the aikikai version of [yokomen uchi shihonage omote](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EENeVTWpe_o).